# Error during import in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, import

Need Solution for the below error. I have dump file to restore in a database. But got a error during import.

```
IMP-00002: failed to open C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\NEFT_IFSC.dmp for read
Import file: EXPDAT.DMP >
```

Comment: Does `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\NEFT_IFSC.dmp` exist? Is it readable? (Why are you still usning the old import/export rather than datapump?)

Comment: I hope you don't actually mean "restore".  EXP/IMP is not meant to be a backup and recovery solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things it could be: file path is wrong, file is corrupt, file is too big, permissions on the directory, file name is wrong, and so on.

You may find it helpful to run your import using a parameter file.  Not only will that save you some typing if you end up re-running this several times, it will give you the possibility to review what you're about to submit.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL1645).

Also you can set the `SHOW=Y` parameter to validate the contents of the file.